# Insert values in Hive tables with primitive and complex data type

Tags: hive, hiveql

If i have only one table such as student and table definition and schema is such as 
hive>

```
create table student1(S_Id int,
    > S_name Varchar(100),
    > Address Struct<a:int, b:String, c:int>,
    > marks Map<String, Int>);

OK
Time taken: 0.439 seconds
hive> 

hive> Describe Student1;
OK
s_id                    int                                         
s_name                  varchar(100)                                
address                 struct<a:int,b:string,c:int>                        
marks                   map<string,int>                             
Time taken: 0.112 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Now i am trying to insert values into that Student1 table such as

```
hive> insert into table student1 values(1, 'Afzal', Struct(42, 'nelson Ave NY', 08309),MAP("MATH", 89));
```

I am getting that error

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values
```

How do i insert values for one record in one go, Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when using `insert .. select` statement. Create a dummy table with single row, or use some existing table + add `limit 1`. Also use `named_struct` function:

Demo:

```
hive> insert into table student1 
      select 1                                                    s_id, 
             'Afzal'                                              s_name, 
             named_struct('a',42, 'b','nelson Ave NY', 'c',08309) address,
             MAP('MATH', 89)                                      marks 
        from default.dual limit 1; --this is dummy table

Loading data to table dev.student1
Table dev.student1 stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=1, totalSize=48, rawDataSize=37]
OK
Time taken: 27.175 seconds
```

Check data:

```
hive> select * from student1;
OK
1       Afzal   {"a":42,"b":"nelson Ave NY","c":8309}   {"MATH":89}
Time taken: 0.125 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: so i had another table table called student one but this table definition is not same as that, i tried as your in hive such as insert into table student 1 select 1 s_id,'Afzal' s_name,named_struct('a',42,'b','nelson Ave NY','c',08309) address, MAP('Math',89)
    > from student limit 1;
OK
                                                                                             after that i query that table i am not getting any data below its respone                                                                                                select * from student1;
OK
no results

Comment: hive> insert into table student1 
    > select 1 s_id,
    > 'Afzal' s_name,
    > named_struct('a',42, 'b','nelson ave NY','c',08309) address,
    > MAP('Math', 89) marks
    > from afzal.student limit 1;
Query ID = cloudera_20180427113434_171694e8-ccd2-4d78-bf6c-f84b459d2d0f
 but still not getting any output from the query.

Comment: @MdAfzalHossain And you do not need dummy table with the same structure since you are selecting constants, not columns from table. Any not empty table is OK

Comment: Thank you @leftjoin, it worked now, Thank you so much for your explanation and it was easy to follow, i really appreciate you. Thanks again

Comment: i accept that answer and already click that, i dont know why it is still 1.

Comment: i was wondering if i have a file with all those information, then how do i load that file with that schema, in this case do i also need to use another table which has atleast one row. if you please also show a demo for that will be much appreciate

Comment: @MdAfzalHossain Try to use Tez instead of MR. It seems it works on Tez without dummy table.

Comment: @MdAfzalHossain If you can confirm it works on Tez without dummy table, then I will edit the answer with this update, so it will be more helpful for others. I cannot test your examplet right now. But it worked for me with STACK type on Tez, and it was the same exception without dummy table on MR

Comment: @MdAfzalHossain the best way to load data from file is to create table on top of file location or put file into table location